# Printing items in a list that occur a certain number of times?

Tags: python, list, count

Given a list of items, e.g.

```
words = ['apple', 'apple', 'boat', 'cat', 'apple', 'cat']
```

I  can count the occurrence of each element. I only want to print out the elements that are in the list three times, i.e. in the list above 'apple' occurs three times so I want this to be printed. At the moment this is my code:

```
for i in words:
    if words.count(i) == 3:
        print(i)
```

But this prints 'apple' three times. How do I make it only print 'apple' once?

Edit: This program will be reading in many words, and it needs to print out the ones stored in the list three times, but they need to be printed in the same order, i.e. I think this means I can't use set(), how else can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is O(N^2), but this can be solved in O(N).

```
from collections import Counter
print [key for key, count in Counter(words).items() if count == 3]
```

In this solution, `Counter(words)` will find the frequency of all items in the list. If you print the Counter object, it will be something like this

```
Counter({'apple': 3, 'cat': 2, 'boat': 1})
```

This is done in O(N) and then we iterate over that object to find all the keys whose values are `3`. This is again O(N).

Just for the sake of completeness, I post the plain dictionary version

```
counter = {}
for word in words:
    counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1
print [key for key, count in counter.items() if count == 3]
```

The `dict.get` method, will look for the first parameter in the dictionary. If that is found, it will return the value corresponding to that. Otherwise, it will return the second parameter (default value).

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the [comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696046/printing-items-in-a-list-that-occur-a-certain-number-of-times/21696084#comment32802699_21696155), if you want the order to be retained, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`, like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
counter = OrderedDict()
words = ['cat', 'apple', 'apple', 'boat', 'cat', 'apple', 'cat']
for word in words:
    counter[word] = counter.get(word, 0) + 1
print [key for key, count in counter.items() if count == 3]
```

**Output**

```
['cat', 'apple']
```

It maintains the order in which the keys are inserted in the dictionary now.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built in `set` function that removes duplicates from a list. You can either modify your code like this:

```
for i in set(words):
    if words.count(i) == 3:
        print(i)
```

Or you could use a list comprehension, as I have now been told it's called:

`[print(i) for i in set(words) if words.count(i)==3]`

This works because `set(words)` returns only the unique elements of `words`, but it does not affect the results of `words.count(i)`.

Comment: That is not a generator, but list comprehension. This is again in O(N^2)

Comment: @thefourtheye For a while, I called them "constructors", even. The manuals about it are really messed up. I'll fix, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, but for the output to be in the same format as the original code, you'd need to `'\n'.join()` the list, raising the computation time, or bring `print()` into the 'list comprehension'.

Comment: I agree. But that will still be considered as O(N) only.

Comment: @thefourtheye Yeah, your answer is better.

Comment: So I just implemented this into my program, and it works well, except it prints out the list of words in a different order every time, what causes this? I need them to be printed in the same order as they occur in the document I am getting them from

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas I'm not entirely sure; `set` seems to go in whatever order it wants. Try @thefourtheye's answer.

Comment: @HayleyvanWaas Please check my updated answer in the `Edit` section

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set.

```
set([word for word in words if words.count(word) == 3])
```